SELECT * FROM my_table where match('ZS'); not worked in manticore
I have install manticore successfully.and my manticore config file is:
source my_source{
  type            = mysql
  sql_host        = 127.0.0.1
  sql_user        = test
  sql_pass        = iflytek
  sql_db          = test
  sql_query       = SELECT id,xxx FROM json_test1sql_field_string = xxx
  sql_query_pre   = SET NAMES utf8;
}

table my_table{
  source       = my_source
  path         = /var/lib/sphinx/my_table
  min_word_len    = 3
  ngram_len = 1
  charset_table = non_cjk
}

searchd {
  listen = 0.0.0.0:9312
  listen = 0.0.0.0:9306:mysql
  listen = 0.0.0.0:9308:http
  seamless_rotate = 1
  preopen_indexes = 1
  unlink_old = 1
  log = /var/log/manticore/searchd.log
}

the result of SELECT id,xxx FROM json_test1 is:



id
xxx




1
SzOAG2Lyck


2
nmP6dwbxc5


3
HjUy2RfTBQ


***



18
mcXKNxVfnd


19
yaQJzyouvl


20
ZSaubNxKBu


***




But when I execute:
mysql -h0 -P9306

MySQL [(none)]> SELECT * FROM my_table where match('"yaQJ"');
Empty set (0.01 sec)

If I wrote whole string it worked:
MySQL [(none)]> SELECT * FROM my_table where match('yaQJzyouvl');
+------+------------+
| id   | xxx        |
+------+------------+
|   19 | yaQJzyouvl |
+------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Can anyone tell me how to fulltext that column data? Thanks!!
I try to modify my config file:
min_word_len    = 3 
ngram_len = 1

for many times. But this problem still exists.

You should have received a syntax error for using match without against. match provides list of columns, against provides the text you are searching for. Therefore your question is unclear.

You do not need in FULLTEXT. Use common LIKE.

Thanks for your answer. Originally I notice SELECT * FROM my_table where xxx like '%TBQ'  and SELECT * FROM my_table where xxx like '%TBQ%' . Such SQL can not use index and There is too many records in my_table(10000000+).
So I use fulltext search to do that.
